# What happenes if you apply the Fourier transform for $n$ times to a function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know that $\mathcal{F} \{\mathcal{F} \{ \mathcal{F} \{ \mathcal{F} \{ f(t) \}\}\}\} = f(t)$.
How can I prove this statement?

Also, whith whom are equal 
$\mathcal{F} \{ \mathcal{F}\{ f(t) \}\}$ and $\mathcal{F} \{ \mathcal{F} \{\mathcal{F} \{ f(t) \}\}\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
\begin{align}
[\mathcal{F}^2 f](x) = f(-x), \  \ [\mathcal{F}^3 f](x) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}f(x)= [\mathcal{F} f](-x)   \ \ \text{ and } \ \ [\mathcal{F}^4 f](x) = f(x).
\end{align}

Edit: Let me do the first computation. Observe
\begin{align}
[\mathcal{F}^2f](x)=&\   \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \left[\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(t)e^{-2\pi i \xi t}\ dt \right]e^{-2\pi i \xi x}\ d\xi\\
=&\ \int^\infty_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-\infty} f(t) e^{-2\pi i\xi(x+t)}\ dtd\xi\\
=&\  \int^\infty_{-\infty}f(t)\left[\int^\infty_{-\infty}  e^{-2\pi i\xi(x+t)}\ d\xi\right] dt\\
=&\ \int^\infty_{-\infty} f(t)\delta(x+t)\ dt = f(-x). 
\end{align}

Comment: usually we prove the Parseval theorem, so that $\mathcal{F}$ is unitary $L^2 \to L^2$, proving that $\mathcal{F}\mathcal{F}^* =\mathcal{F}^*\mathcal{F}= Id$, and $\mathcal{F}^*[f](\xi) = \mathcal{F}[f](-\xi)$ is obvious. Then, we extend it to tempered distributions, by looking at $\phi(x) (T \ast \varphi(x))$

Comment: I obtain that $[\mathcal{F}^3f](x) = \mathcal{F}\{f(-x)\}$. Am I right?

Comment: @Ștefan You are correct.